# Como definir un alias a columnas con el mismo nombre en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

tengo una duda. 
como defino el alias para columnas con el mismo nombre????.
En concreto deseo realizar una consulta a mi Base de Datos con registros relacionados con laravel de l siguiente manera

```
$proveedor =DB::table('proveedors')
            ->join('pais', 'proveedors.id_pais', '=', 'pais.id_pais')
            ->join('departamentos', 'proveedors.id_departamento', '=', 
              'departamentos.id_departamento')                ->select('nombre','representante','cargo','direccion','telefono','pais.nombre','departamentos.nombre', 'email','notas')
            ->where('id_proveedor', '=', $id)
            ->get();
```

Pero me devuelve error por la ambigüedad en los nombres de columna.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar alias de la siguiente manera:

```
$select =DB::table('tabla1 as t1')
->join('tabla2 as t2', 't1.id', '=','t2.id_tabla1')
->select('t1.uncampo','t2.otrocampo')
->where('t1.uncampo', '=', $id)
->get();
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchisiamas gracias fue de bastante ayuda tu aporte